# python - rewrite a file with modifications

Tags: python, replace

I have a file called inputs.txt and I am trying to replace a string in that file with the value of a function. The problem is I am not able to write to that file. I just started learning python so struggling with this. Any help please.

When I have it as a string it works fine

Content of the file

```
[aws_s3://MAC_10]
key_name = ABC/YYZZ/daily
```

Desired output

```
[aws_s3://MAC_2014-12-31]
key_name = ABC/YYZZ/daily/2014-12-31_
```

I wrote the function which gets the time value as

```
def change_time(match):
    match = match.group()
    date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    value = str(date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    return value
```

I was able to open the file and read and match content but I am not able to write to it

```
f=open('test.txt','w')
```

`print re.sub(r'_[0-9-]+',change_time,string)` outputs the required changed first line to stdout, but how do I modify the contents of the file?

Comment: So the question is actually how to read the contents of a file?

Comment: It seems to me that you are relatively new to programming, as well as to python.  Nothing wrong with that, but if this is not true then we may have drastically misunderstood your question...

Comment: Yes. Never did any coding before. Slowly trying to pick it up. My question is how to match a pattern and replace the pattern in the same file. I was able to figure out how to write a function to get the desired output time format, but never could figure out on how to read and write to a same file.

Comment: that makes sense.  I think you're thinking of a file as you would see it in an editor, where when you insert a new character all the other characters slide to the right.  Instead, writing to a file deletes everything in the file after the write point.  You need to read the whole file into memory, modify the copy in memory, and then completely rewrite the file (see my answer below)

Answer (score 3):

Reading and writing the same file can be tricky, but the `fileinput` module of the standard library supports that well:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(['inputs.txt'], inplace=True):
    print re.sub(r'_[0-9-]+', change_time, line) ,
```

I'm giving the Python 2 form of `print` because it seems that's what you're using.  Anyway, in Python 3 it would be similar and more readable:

```
    print(re.sub(r'_[0-9-]+', change_time, line), end='')
```

At any rate, `fileinput` redirects standard output so that all `print`s go to the very file you're reading (when the `inplace=True` has been set) -- you need to print out all you're reading in, with changes were needed.  Works on as many files as you need (note that the first argument is a list of filenames), no matter how big they are, etc, etc.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html for much, much more:-)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I will try this method. Is it possible to include a capture group in re.sub?

Comment: @user3232552, sure!  I just copied the RE pattern you had used, but you can really do any processing you like to `line` between the moment you read it in (in the `for` clause of the loop) and the moment you `print` (a possibly modified version of it) out again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not programmed much, it might be easy to think of a file as it is seen in an editor, where you can position your cursor at a particular point and insert characters at that point, causing other characters in the file to "slide to the right".  Writing to a file does not work this way.  Instead, writing a file at a particular point deletes all file contents after that point, meaning that you need to read the whole file into memory, modify the contents of the file, and then write the contents back out to the file.

More specifically, since the file will have a different number of bytes in it after your modifications, and all the insertion/deletion of characters do not happen at the end of the file, here is the procedure you *generally* want to follow:

First, you read the entire contents of the file into memory, something like

```
import io
with io.open('file.ini') as fobj:
    contents = fobj.read()
```

Note that after this code has run, the file is closed again: you have copied the contents of the file into memory, and the file remains unchanged on disk.

Next, you modify the contents of the file in your desired way

```
def change_time(match):
    match = match.group()
    date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    value = str(date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    return value

new_contents = re.sub(r'_[0-9-]+',change_time,contents)
```

Now, you re-open the file in write mode.  This immediately throws away the contents of the file, and you write back your own (now modified) copy from memory

```
with io.open('file.ini','wb') as fobj:
    fobj.write(new_contents)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to clearly state how each part works. I think I have a better understanding of how to read and write to files now.

Comment: Is there a way to add a string to the key_name = ABC/YYZZ/ and make it key_name = ABC/YYZZ/daily/2014-12-31 ? re.sub rex pattern is overwriting the whole value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to read in value, edit change in memory and write our new value

```
contents = open('file.ini').read()
contents = re.sub(r'_[0-9-]+',change_time,contents)
with open('file.ini', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(contents)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This helps in how to write it to a file. Is there way to capture a value in regex and just change that? Can re.sub understand a capture group and replace values just for that?